# Why does SparkLauncher return immediately and spawn no job?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-launcher

I am using `SparkLauncher` in Spark v1.6.0. My problem is that when I use this class to launch my Spark jobs, it returns immediately and no job is submitted. My code is as follows.

```
new SparkLauncher()
 .setAppName("test word count")
 .setAppResource("file://c:/temp/my.jar")
 .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
 .setMaster("spark://master:7077")
 .startApplication(new SparkAppHandler.Listener() {
   @Override public void stateChanged(SparkAppHandle h) { }
   @Override public void infoChanged(SparkAppHandle h) { } 
  });
```

When I debug into the code, I notice, to my surprise, that all this clazz really does is calls a script `spark-submit.cmd` using `ProcessBuilder`.

```
[C:/tmp/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit.cmd, --master, spark://master:7077, --name, "test word count", --class, my.spark.appMain, C:/temp/my.jar]
```

However, if I run this command (the one that is run by `ProcessBuilder`) directly on the console, a Spark job is submitted. Any ideas on what's going on?

There's another method `SparkLauncher.launch()` that is available, but the javadocs say to avoid this method.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried putting some code into the two listener methods to report state and info changes as your app is submitted?

Comment: So, what happened? Did you get it to work using SparkLauncher? I know SparkLauncher internally calls ./spark-submit with a ProcessBuilder wrapper on it but I am hoping it gives better life cycle management through the various listeners.

Answer (score 5):

If it works in the console but not from your program, you may need to tell the SparkLauncher where your Spark home is by:

```
.setSparkHome("C:/tmp/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
```

But there could be other things going wrong. You may want to capture additional debugging information by using:

```
.addSparkArg("--verbose")
```

and

```
Map<String, String> env = Maps.newHashMap();
env.put("SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND", "1");
```

Pass the env object to the SparkLauncher constructor:

```
new SparkLauncher(env)
```

Answer (score 3):

How do you place the `new SparkLauncher()` statement in the program?

If the main program/unit test immediately finishes after invoking `.startApplication()`, then the child-process created by it is terminated as well.

You can check the state of the job with the handle created

```
SparkAppHandle handle = new SparkLauncher()
    .setAppName("test word count")
    .setAppResource("file://c:/temp/my.jar")
    .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
    .setMaster("spark://master:7077")
    .startApplication();

handle.getState();  // immediately returns UNKNOWN

Thread.sleep(1000); // wait a little bit...

handle.getState();  // the state may have changed to CONNECTED or others
```

I think that it is because the application takes a certain time to connect to the master, if the program ends before the connection is established, then no job is submitted.

Comment: how is this helping what the OP asked?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wait for the launcher to get connected to driver nd get you app id and status. For that you can do while loop or something similar.
eg.

```
   while(!handle.getState().isFinal()) { 
   logger.info("Current state: "+ handle.getState()) 
   logger.info("App Id "+ handle.getAppId());
   Thread.sleep(1000L);
   // other stuffs you want to do 
   //
   }
```